# Get effective permissions of shared folder

Tags: c++, winapi, permissions

There is server (ip 192.168.5.5) with shared folder "shared", which contains file "file.txt".  Share permissions - everyone has full control, NTFS permissions for "shared" and "shared\file.txt" - everyone can only read. Everyone can connect to this computer without password (as guest).

From another computer I try to check write permissions for current user via  [GetFileSecurity/OpenProcessToken/DuplicateToken/AccessCheck](http://blog.aaronballman.com/2011/08/how-to-check-access-rights/):

but result of function

```
CanAccessFolder( TEXT( "\\\\192.168.5.5\\shared\\file.txt" ), GENERIC_WRITE )
```

is TRUE (really i don't have these rights).

I tried to use [AccessChk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/accesschk):

```
accesschk64.exe "denis"  "\\192.168.5.5\shared\file.txt"
```

It also returns, that i can write to this file:

```
RW \\192.168.5.5\shared\file.txt
```

Why is this happening? 
Is it possible to get effective rights of shared folder?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: SMB shared, I assume, not something exotic like NFS?

Comment: Is it possible that you actually DO have permission? Because ACL entries are applied in order, an explicit grant that precedes an explicit deny will take precedence. An explicit deny only works if there are no prior explicit grants.

Comment: @MSalters I tried to edit the file using Notepad - access denied

Comment: Since we don't know, what access or share mode Notepad requests, this is of rather little help. Open the file using `CreateFile`, passing the desired access and share mode.

Comment: `auto h = CreateFile(
      L"\\\\192.168.5.5\\\shared\\file.txt",
      GENERIC_READ,
      FILE_SHARE_READ,
      NULL,
      OPEN_EXISTING,
      FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
      NULL
);`
`std::cerr << GetLastError() << "\n"; `
print "0"


`auto h = CreateFile(
      L"\\\\192.168.5.5\\\shared\\file.txt",
      GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
      FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
      NULL,
      OPEN_EXISTING,
      FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
      NULL
);`
`std::cerr << GetLastError() << "\n"; `

print "5"